# readln of InputStreamReader doesn't work

Tags: java, netbeans, vpn, telnet

I have to send and receive with server some stream using java. 
The protocol is telnet and if I use cmd in windows with this commands:`"telnet 10.0.1.5 9100"` and after `"^AI202"` I have a response.

The code java:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;

public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {

    Socket s = new Socket();

    PrintWriter s_out = null;

    BufferedReader s_in = null;

    String remoteip = "10.0.1.5";

    int remoteport = 9100;

    s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(remoteip , remoteport));

    s_out = new PrintWriter( s.getOutputStream(), true);

    s_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

    String message = "^AI202";

    try{

    System.out.println(s_in.readLine());

    }

    catch(Error e){

    System.out.println(e);

    }

    s_out.close();

    s_in.close();

    s.close();

}
```

The problem is the same: `s_in` call method `readLine()` and program cycle infinite.

Comment: sorry i've missed "s_out.append(message);" but also the same problem

Comment: You are trying to read from the socket. Is there any data to read? Is the remote end sending anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think System.out.println(s_in.readLine()); will try to read it over and over again, failing each time and causing infinite loop.

Try

```
 String line ="";

 while ((line = s_in.readLine()) != null) { 

      // Do what you want to do with line.          

}
```

[Java Socket BufferReader.readline get null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845410/java-socket-bufferreader-readline-get-null)

Comment: if i put s_in.readLine() in a string and i try to print the string i've the same problem

Comment: the same... I've started with debug mode and i've noted that the inputstream have 8000 and more character with the same value '\u0000'

Comment: readLine will block until it has read an entire lien from the socket. Is the remote end sending a line terminated by a newline character?

Comment: @user2053994 \u0000 means null character...yes?

Comment: yes is null character. The remote send line with newline characters

Comment: @user2053994  May be client closes the socket before sending message. This causes at the other side of the socket (your server) that the BufferedReader returns null when you ask the next line.

Comment: @user2053994 I pasted a link above view that and let me know your problem get solved or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `telnet` protocol does not terminate commands with line breaks.

Change your read block to

```
  try {
    char [] cbuf = new char[7];
    System.out.println(s_in.read(cbuf, 0, cbuf.length));
  } catch(Error e){
    System.out.println(e);
  }
```

And you will get some input.

Comment: Not sure. I just saw the packet on _wireshark_ and the first exchange is 7 bytes long No _new line_ character at the end.

Comment: still having the same problem whit this change too

Comment: But are you getting any output? If not, install [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) so you can check the network activity and see what packets are exchanged. Otherwise it is going to be difficult to debug...